# Invalid object name 'dbo.UserNotes'. exception - ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

It appears that EF doesn't create this one table

NotesModels.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace note.DO.Models
{
public class NotesContext : DbContext
{
    public NotesContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserNotes> Notes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserNotes")]
public class UserNotes
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int NoteId { get; set; }

    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Added { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Edited { get; set; }  
}

public class CreateNoteModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Author")]
    public UserProfile Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Added on")]
    public DateTime? AddedOn { get; set; }
}
}
```

I generated controller using those classes. However, when I attempt to add a note, I get following exception:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.UserNotes'.

...triggered by this line:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

Things I have tried:

- changing schema to "dbo" (by adding [Table("UserNotes", Schema:"dbo")]))
- manually removing entire database file from Visual Studio
- changing plurar forms to singular and back
- reinstalling Entity Framework

Any ideas? Perhaps there is something really stupid that I'm doing and not noticing?

EDIT: UserProfile class and data context:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

(...)

(other models)
```

Comment: What if you made this: `public DbSet<UserNotes> Notes { get; set; }`
 and changed it to this: `public DbSet<UserNotes> UserNotes { get; set; }`.  I thought it had to match naming convention?

Comment: Does the table exist in your db?

Comment: The table is never created in the db. I have tried renaming Notes to UserNotes, it didn't help.

Comment: What kind of class is `UserProfile`?

Comment: Public if that's what you mean. Looks basically the same as UserNotes.

Comment: I mean, is it part of the mapped class model, as the other two classes are?

Comment: I have added the code to the first post. UserProfile is a default class generated when you start a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

Comment: You must have one context that contains all classes to generate a database. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Gert Arnold's comment, I did this

Added this line to UsersContext:

```
public DbSet<UserNotes> Notes { get; set; }
```

So this is how it looks now:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notes> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

And it works flawlessly! Table is now being created and I can add entries without any problems.